# Brake lever suddenly stuck due to an overtightened screw - what went wrong?

Tags: brake-levers, adjustment-screw

**The issue**
I was biking when suddenly it felt like I was driving in the sand and not on a regular road.

Upon inspection, I noticed that the brake was stuck on the 'closed' position, closing the disc brake and well, preventing me from biking correctly.

Here's a picture of the culprit screw - a **six pan headless screw** that went far into the body pushing the handle as far as it was totally stuck:
[image]

**My repair**
I unscrewed it as shown on the picture. I could see the handle slowly getting back to a normal position. But that looks weird to me.

I checked on the other handle, and there's no screw. I guess it fell off.

**Questions**

- Is my repair safe, and should I be worried about the screw missing on the other handle?
- What is the purpose of that screw? to me the only purpose it can have is to create an accident/leave me stranded. I'm not sure I should not simply remove them...
- Any idea of "what went wrong" for that screw to suddenly be overtightened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those screws are the "reach adjustment" screws. They control the resting positions of the brake levers, ensuring they're easy to grab regardless of your hand size. Without them, the levers will rest at the farthest position away from the handlebars. This is not a safety issue unless you have small hands and hence run the risk of being unable to reach the brake levers in an emergency. However, you *would* be best off consulting a local bike mechanic to inspect your braking system. I can't think of why your brakes would have suddenly engaged like that--it would likely require some extensive (in-person) visual inspection and diagnosis to figure out what happened.

[image]

Image source: https://www.cyclemaintenanceacademy.com/brakes/adjust-brake-lever-reach/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. If my understanding is correct, they are useful as long as someone properly resets the brake cable tension after adjusting the screw, am I right?

Comment: @FunkyBezel Yeah, they make accessing the brake lever significantly more comfortable (and as I mentioned, for smaller hands, they are almost mandatory safety equipment). However, unless you were fiddling with the thing on the road and that's why the brake activated, there shouldn't be a need to mess with cable tension. Reach adjust is usually set-and-forget.

Comment: Perfectly clear, thanks.